# Can't load images from external storage in M preview

Tags: android, picasso, android-ion, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an app that stores it's images on the external storage. This have been working great up until I tried the new M preview.

I use picasso (I even tried Ion) to load the images and I get the images with the "file:///mnt/sdcard/*appname*/image1.jpg" URI.

I don't get any errors at all, but I'm guessing that M has changed the permissions to read from external storage. I have tried googling but I come up empty.

Writing the images to the external storage works just as normal by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although siris_cac answer was very well explained it wasn't what caused my problem. 
Turns out I can't use "file:///mnt/sdcard/appname/image1.jpg" to load the file from external storage in M.

I guess it might have something to to with http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/05/28/android-m-feature-spotlight-external-storage-can-be-adopted-as-true-internal-storage-or-accessed-normally-with-no-additional-apps/

I guess I was wrong from the begining not using the Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory() when loading images, only when saving them.

So now to load images I use:

```
"file:///" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/appname/image1.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking if the permission is granted by :

```
checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

And try requesting permissions on Runtime like this using `requestPermissions()`.

```
int EXT_PERMISSION = 1;
requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
```

And,
Handle the Permission Granted result

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case EXT_PERMISSION: {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
              //permission granted
            } else {
              //permission denied
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't changed anything though. To my understanding the new permission is only if you build against M?

Comment: Yes. It's only if your'e targeting M. I suppose the same code which you've now, works on previous versions.

Comment: Yes it works great on old versions of android. But do you mean that pretty much all apps will crash or get unexpected behavior on M unless they get an update to build with M SDK ? Because I can't even use the requestPermissions method with my old SDK?

Comment: I faced the similar problem on WhatsApp. The app would just open a Camera instance but not a ImagePicker or a Gallery instance. 
You can very well add a check condition if the Build version is greater than M before calling `requestPermissions()`.